# how to uninstall pcl1.7 in ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: c++, ubuntu

I want to follow the steps below:

step 1: locate pcl
step 2: remove things contain pcl in /usr
step 3: remove /home/pcl/build/

Are there any things I need to be careful?

Thx!

Comment: Just take a look at the following link: https://askubuntu.com/questions/873935/how-to-uninstall-a-program-in-linux

It is a generated way to uninstall a programme from Ubuntu. Hope that I helped you.

Comment: Perhaps you're looking for yum or apt to uninstall PCL?

Comment: @dpap I tried sudo make uninstall, but it failed.

Comment: @Wh.94 If that so, please edit your question and upload screenshots to help you.

Comment: @Chipster I installed pcl by source code.

Comment: Ah. Well. Is there instructions how to uninstall it packaged with it?

Comment: Typically, well behaved software packages install themselves under `/usr/local` when building from source. Just delete anything under `/usr/local` that you feel deleting. Anything important under that path should only be something you have put there.

Comment: @HAL9000 yes, thank you.

Comment: @Chipster just follow HAL9000.

Answer (score 2):

You may try running`sudo make uninstall` in your build directory of pcl1.7. Usually that will automatically remove the installed files in your system.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your question and comments properly,your process of uninstalling it failed. I think what you are looking for is :

```
sudo apt-get purge pcl*
```

Answer (score 0):

step 1: locate pcl
step 2: remove things contain pcl in /usr/local/include/ and /usr/local/lib/
step 3: remove /home/pcl/build/